# Bootstrap checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been developing a web application using bootstrap 3.0.2 and jQuery. But I've some problems with checkboxes. Imagine that I’ve the following checkbox:

```
<label class="checkbox margin-left5">
<input type="checkbox" name="xptoName" id="xptoNameId">
Hello World
</label>
```

So i want to check/uncheck through jQuery. For that, I use this function:

```
function checking(isToCheck, id){
 $("#"+id).attr('checked', isToCheck);
}
```

If you call the first time this function:

```
checking(true, "xptoNameId");
```

It'll check the checkbox, but if I called several times after this, for checking and unchecking the checkbox will not check again.

Any clue for this strange behavior?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check checkbox checked property using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/check-checkbox-checked-property-using-jquery)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
function checking(isToCheck, id) {
    $("#" + id).prop('checked', isToCheck);
}
```

Read [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)